# Configuring Lighttpd, PHP5 and MySQL5 for a no-supervision installation

Tags: php, mysql, lighttpd, offline

I'm creating a script that'll work on a Lighttpd, PHP5 and MySql5. The point is, it must be full-offline script installed and configured with all the requirements by one installer. It's a bit modified wiki thing. How to do a such thing?

Comment: So have you done anything so far, if so can you post the code?

Comment: no, just asking for possible solutions

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to install a whole installation of Lighty, PHP + Mysql or are you just trying to get something installed in a preconfigured environment?

I'd package it up as a VM if you need to install everything

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you the NSIS install system and look for examples like this: [MySQL Silent Install](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,143723,143723#msg-143723).